# How can i use OKTA API to create/modify attributes of a public application like O365

Tags: api, okta, okta-api

I have used Postman per the OKTA developer docs to create a new SAML 2.0 app and that works fine. However, I wanted to know how I can modify my code to edit/or create an instance of a published app like Office 365. I posted my question on OKTA forums as well but no response yet. Thanks! - JC
https://devforum.okta.com/t/api-for-public-apps/6151

I have created a custom app using Postman which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, unique application attributes from the Okta Integration Network (OIN) are not exposed to the Okta Management API, based on the app model:

https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/apps/#models.

I suspect this is because each template in the OIN is unique, with its own set of attributes, and because of this it may be tricky to deploy an API intuitive enough to account for this uniqueness.

If you are looking to manage a lot of instances of the same application type, it may be worth looking into creating a default application and creating the connection settings from scratch, instead of using templates from the OIN. Although this may not be an option depending on the app, and if provisioning is involved.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you.